# convert table to div - css

Tags: css

here is my table and how would i convert to divs

```
<table class="style1">
            <tr>
                <td class="style2">Name</td>
                <td class="style5">John Doe</td>
                <td>error</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style2">
                    Desc</td>
                <td class="style5">
                    Desc....</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style3">
                    Start Date</td>
                <td class="style4">
                    date here</td>
                    <td>start date error here</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style2">
                    End Date</td>
                <td class="style5">
                    end date here....</td>
                    <td>end date error..</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style>
   .style2{
float:left;    
}
.clr{
clear:both;
}
</style>

<div class="style1">
            <div class="clr">
                <div class="style2">Name</div>
                <div class="style5">John Doe</div>
            </div>
            <div class="clr">
                <div class="style2">
                    Desc</div>
                <div class="style5">
                    Desc....</div>
            </div>
            <div class="clr">
                <div class="style2">
                    Start Date</div>
                <div class="style4">
                    date here</div>
                    <div>start date error here</div>
            </div>
            <div class="clr">
                <div class="style2">
                    End Date</div>
                <div class="style5">
                    end date here....</div>
                    <div>end date error..</div>
            </div>
  </div>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: what is it style2 and style 4 and style 5

Comment: dont worry about style 4 and 5. what you need to do is to make them inline with style 2. just worry about style2. float'em out

Answer (score 8):

CSS allows for easy table simulation with block elements using the `display` property.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="table style1">
    <div class="tr">
        <div class="td style2">
            Name
        </div>
        <div class="td style5">
            John Doe
        </div>
        <div class="td">
            error
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
        <div class="td style2">
            Desc
        </div>
        <div class="td style5">
            Desc....
        </div>
        <div class="td style5">
            Desc....
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
        <div class="td style3">
            Start Date
        </div>
        <div class="td style4">
            date here
        </div>
        <div class="td">
            start date error here
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
        <div class="td style2">
            End Date
        </div>
        <div class="td style5">
            end date here....
        </div>
        <div class="td">
            end date error..
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.table {
    display:table;
}
.tr {
    display:table-row;
}
.td {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Comment: This answers the question, but would use this html, or would you leave it in a table?

Comment: I'd leave it in a table but that's not what the OP asked ;)

Comment: I wanted your opinion on it, as if the OP is trying to explore non table-based layouts, i want to make sure he also gets the idea that this isn't a "how other's do it" example.  It is a good example though - wasn't trying to knock it down.

Comment: Yep, no worries. I agree divs aren't the end-all solution. Tabular data should be placed in a tabular structure. My example was primarily to illustrate how CSS has the ability to replicate the layout.

Answer (score 2):

If you are displaying data like that it is best to use a table. `<div>`'s are recommended over tables for more general layout, but in this case you would have to apply css in every `<div>` instead of using plain `<table>`, `<tr>`, and `<td>` elements to maintain the styling.

Answer (score 0):

Semantically speaking, your data is tabular, which means a `<table>` is best instead of a `<div>`.  `<div>`'s would be used for generic structure.  But you should always strive for semantic code.

e.g. if the content is a paragraph, then use `<p>`.  If you have a list, then use an a list - unordered or ordered etc..

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, however I wound up here and others may come this way as well. I used AlienWebGuy's technique to replace a table with `<div>'`s styled using the display property. Doing this fixed a maddening vertical alignment problem I had with a table that contained `<td>` elements that in turn contained differing numbers of lines.